# Как вставить несколько списков в одну строку таблицы PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

Добрый день дамы и господа! Помогите пожалуйста с ситуацией разобраться.
Есть несколько списков сформированных из разных запросов. Их надо вставить в другую БД в одну строку.
Мне в голову не пришло ничего умнее объединить эти списки в один и вставить таким способом:

```
sql_reqest = '''INSERT INTO place_report (col1, clo2, ..., col58)
                            VALUES (%s, %s, ..., %s)'''

cur.execute(sql_reqest, val_list)
```

Но, как понимаете, когда надо заполнить 58 колонок это та еще "порнография")))
Подскажите пожалуйста более оптимальный вариант этой операции.

Comment: *как понимаете, когда надо заполнить 58 колонок это та еще "порнография"* Ошибаетесь. Порнография, причём без кавычек - это 58 однотипных полей. Почитайте про нормализацию данных... хоть что-нибудь.

Comment: @Akina тут такое дело, базу делал не я, и изменять ее не могу...

Answer (score 0):

Формирование:

```
values = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s)", (x, y, z)).decode('utf-8') for x, y, z in zip(list1, list2, list3))
```

Вставка в БД:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES " + values) conn.commit()
```

Экспериментируйте.